# Is there a need for a boolean field index in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to optimize my elasticsearch.
I have several boolean fields, which I use queries with.
I could dispense with them, but that would give my client side a hard time.

My question is whether or not setting those fields to `"index":"yes"` will actually have a significant negative effect on my index's performance, such as indexing time and size (other than the obvious "store" space it would take)?

Does a boolean indexed field really take up more space? It seems it shouldn't. Moreover, I don't see any benefit in creating such an index for any DB, not only elasticsearch.

But, I have to specify `"index":"yes"` to be able to filter by it, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to search against a field you have to index it. By default a `boolean` field is indexed, and will take a small amount of space to do so. There will be a list of docs where `"myfield": true` and `"myfield": false`.

If you didn't want to maintain this index, then when you wanted to find docs where `"myfield": true` you would have to through every doc to check the field.

If you don't want to search/filter with that field, by all means set `"index": "no"`, just be warned you will need to re-index everything if you change your mind about this field in the future!

[Have a look at the elasticsearch docs on mappings; the core types section](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/boolean.html), scroll down to the boolean type.

Comment: What you said makes alot of sense.

My intuition is that if I have an index for a boolean field, then the use of that boolean index is, go to the place in the boolean index for the hash of the document id and see if it belongs in the "true" or "false" group.

Isn't that the same effort as going to the hash of the doc_id in the storage, and look at the field value?

Essentially I don't see how the computational effort of checking if an item is in a set (of true or false), is smaller then the effort of checking that field value on the server side.

Comment: Sure, but are you doing a lookup or a search?

I was doing a search, i.e.: give me docs with myfield = true. 

If you already have the document id and want to know the value of the field, why would you ever use an index?

Comment: I was doing a search (/filter). I see what you're saying. Thanks!